# Metodo en el restcotnroadvice para no usar try cath en un Unhandled exception type JsonProcessingException

Tags: java, spring-boot, excepciones

en el servicio tengo este metodo

```
Override
    public Reserva aniadirSearch(Search search) {
        logger.info("Creamos el objeto Search y seteamos la reserva que viene como parametro");
        reservaRepository.save(search);
        Reserva reserva = new Reserva(search);
        search.setReserva(reserva);
        searchRepository.save(reserva);
        logger.info("Guardamos en la BD");
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        String jsonMessage = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(search);
        logger.info("Enviamos el mensaje");
        kafkaTemplate.send("hotel_availability_searches", jsonMessage);

        return reserva;
    }
```

tengo

```
@RestControllerAdvice
public class ControladorErrores {
@ExceptionHandler(JsonExcepcion.class)
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
    public ResponseEntity<String> handleJsonProcessingException(JsonProcessingException ex) {
        logger.error("Error al procesar el JSON", ex);
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST).body("Error al procesar el JSON");
    }
}
```

y la clase

```
public class JsonExcepcion extends JsonProcessingException {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 5L;
    private final int codigoError;

    public JsonExcepcion(int codigoError, String msg) {
        super(msg);
        this.codigoError = codigoError;
    }

    public static long getSerialversionuid() {
        return serialVersionUID;
    }

    public int getCodigoError() {
        return codigoError;
    }
}
```

pero no consigo que desaparezca el error uqe me obliga a usar un try cath o un throw y quiero que se encarge el controadvice

Answer (score 0):

Al parecer estas implementando una interfaz que tiene el método

```
public Reserva aniadirSearch(Search search)
```

Entendiendo el problema que tienes, no quieres implementar un Try Catch dentro de ese método y tampoco quieres añadirle al método el Throw JsonProcessingException

```
public Reserva aniadirSearch(Search search) throw JsonProcessingException
```

Mi recomendación aquí, uno es que implementes el método haciendo clean code, osea que el método haga solamente una cosa, allí tu método está haciendo multiples cosas, algo así como esto

```
private String buildJsonMessage(Search search) {
try {
 ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        return objectMapper.writeValueAsString(search);
} catch(JsonProcessingException exception) {
 throws new JsonExcepcion(1, exception.getMessage());
}
}
```

Y lo ejecutas desde el método principal, así quedaría limpio el código y segundo, para que el controller advice de spring entienda que hubo una exception custom tuya, hay que implementar que se lance esa excepción como mostré en el ejemplo con el bloque del catch.

Comment: si ya tengo un cath para que quiero el control adivice ya recoge e erro el cath. no? diferente 2es si sale un list x ejemplo pue si list esta vacio  throws new ErrorNotContent(404, dicho objeto no esta en la bd); x ejemplo aqui nadie recoge la excepcion entonce si hace su rtabajo el ocntrol advice

Comment: Claro pero al hacer el object mapper del json el va a lanzar la exception propia (jsonprocessingexception) si sucede un error y tu controller advice esta escuchando es tu exception custom que nunca es lanzada en ninguna parte del código